# find max values and change others to zero

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have 3 vectores in same size like:
`x = [1  2 3 3 4 5 5 5]`,
`A = [30 40 50 52 60 70 73 71]`,
`B = [10 20 40 50 40 30 20 40]`.
Now I want to see in x and find the index of the same values (3,3)(5,5,5) in the x.
then see the values of same index in B (40,50)(30 20 40), then change this valus to have only the maximum one and the other is 0. that means my resualt is
`Bx=[10 20 0 50 40 0 0 40]`
and then use this index of not zero values of Bx to have the values of A as
`Abx=[30 40 0 52 0 0 71]`.

can anybody help me?

Comment: Is `x` always sorted?

Comment: yes, but it schuld not be [1 2 3 ...]. it can be [11 15 17 17 20 22 22 ] and so on. but sortet.

Comment: Shouldn't `Ax` be `30 40 0 52 60 0 0 71`? Or how do you obtain it?

Comment: yes sorry you are correct Ax = [30 40 0 52 60 0 0 71]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Using [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

   ```
   Bx = accumarray(x(:), B(:), [], @(x) {(x==max(x)).'*max(x)});
   Bx = horzcat(Bx{:});
   Abx = A.*(Bx~=0);
   ```
2. Using [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

   ```
   e = double(bsxfun(@eq, x(:), x(:).'));
   e(e==0) = NaN;
   ind = max(bsxfun(@times, e, B(:)))==B;
   Bx = B.*ind;
   Abx = A.*ind;
   ```

---

To do this for several rows at once (`x`,`A` and `B` are now matrices): send the first dimension to the third (with `permute`) and work as above:

```
e = double(bsxfun(@eq, permute(x, [2 3 1]), permute(x, [3 2 1])));
e(e==0) = NaN;
ind = squeeze(max(bsxfun(@times, e, permute(B, [2 3 1])))).'==B;
Bx = B.*ind;
Abx = A.*ind;
```

Example:

```
x = [1     2     3     3     4     5     5     5
     3     2     4     4     4     5     5     5]
A = [30    40    50    52    60    70    73    71
     71    73    70    60    52    50    40    30]
B = [10    20    40    50    40    30    20    40
     40    20    30    40    50    40    20    10]
```

result in

```
Bx =
    10    20     0    50    40     0     0    40
    40    20     0     0    50    40     0     0

Abx =
    30    40     0    52    60     0     0    71
    71    73     0     0    52    50     0     0
```

Comment: Beat me on the `bsxfun`! :)

Comment: Your rock guys! Luis and Divakar :)

Comment: now if the x,A,B are not Arrays but Matrixes in same size, and I want to do same proccess in the rows, is there other poassibility as do it in loops?